# How can I access an element in GridView with more rRelativeLayouts

Tags: appium

I am using appium 1.6.5 and trying to access an Element in a GridView with more RelativeLayouts (0-7)

[Screenshot from uiAutomatorViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt8dr.png)
I have already tried all the possible commands

```
// aDriver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.RelativeLayout").get(4)
/*
List<MobileElement> icons = aDriver.findElementsByClassName("\"android.widget.RelativeLayout\"");

icons.get(4).click();
*/

    aDriver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.RelativeLayout\").instance(4)").click();
// INFO: Also using index instead of instance did not hel UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.RelativeLayout\").index(4)").click()
```

but no success and I get the following Errors

```
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.RelativeLayo
ut\").instance(4)","context":"","multiple":false}}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/320ad077-e2fb-4304-9017-bb7aaba0ae1b/element - - ms - -
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.Re
lativeLayout\").instance(4)","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'new UiSelector().className("android.widget.RelativeLayout").instance(4)' using 'ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Parsing selector: new UiSelector().className("android.widget.RelativeLayout").instance(4)
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: java.lang.Class<T> arg: "android.widget.RelativeLayout"
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "android.widget.RelativeLayout"
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: int arg: 4
```

Would appreciate any support 
Thanks

Comment: List<MobileElement> icons = aDriver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.RelativeLayout");

icons .get(4).click();

Comment: Thanks for Answer.
I have tried this also is the same.

Comment: the issue is that I have a login mask, and  after entering credential and click enter a toast message appears and app terminate to android home-screen, because of this may be the element is not found ( the element is on the next page which will not be displayed) 
I have also increased the waiting time but Some How after click enter button next page is not shown and app terminate to Android homescreen

Comment: Also using the command for waiting till any element from next page appear raised a NullPointerException.

wbw.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("packagename:id/logout")))

So I assume the command you have written should be OK, problem is that the page does not appear if it appears I think the element will be found.

Comment: what is the android version of your android device which you are using.

Comment: Thanks shiv The issue is resolved and your command for finding element was working and found also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
List icons = aDriver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.RelativeLayo‌​ut"); icons .get(4).click();